# Intermittent issue with Maven with required class missing

Tags: java, maven

When building ActiveJDBC (I'm the author of the project), it first builds a Maven plugin: https://github.com/javalite/activejdbc/tree/master/activejdbc-instrumentation
After the plugin is installed, it is used on a different project module (this is a multi-module project).
Sometimes the build succeeds and sometimes it breaks with this error message:

```
[INFO] JavaLite - Common .................................. SUCCESS [  4.241 s]
[INFO] JavaLite - Instrumentation Plugin and JavaAgent .... SUCCESS [  2.590 s]
[INFO] JavaLite - ActiveJDBC ORM Framework ................ FAILURE [  5.526 s]
[INFO] JavaLite - DB-Migrator Maven Plugin ................ SKIPPED
[INFO] JavaLite - DB-Migrator Integration Test ............ SKIPPED
[INFO] JavaLite - Git Info Maven plugin ................... SKIPPED
[INFO] JavaLite - ActiveJDBC Root ......................... SKIPPED
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 12.572 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2014-10-27T23:01:22-05:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 26M/271M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.javalite:activejdbc-instrumentation:1.4.10-SNAPSHOT:instrument (default) on project activejdbc: Execution default of goal org.javalite:activejdbc-instrumentation:1.4.10-SNAPSHOT:instrument failed: A required class was missing while executing org.javalite:activejdbc-instrumentation:1.4.10-SNAPSHOT:instrument: javassist/ClassPath
[ERROR] -----------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] realm =    plugin>org.javalite:activejdbc-instrumentation:1.4.10-SNAPSHOT
[ERROR] strategy = org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy
[ERROR] urls[0] = file:/home/igor/projects/javalite/activejdbc/activejdbc-instrumentation/target/activejdbc-instrumentation-1.4.10-SNAPSHOT.jar
[ERROR] urls[1] = file:/home/igor/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-utils/1.1/plexus-utils-1.1.jar
[ERROR] urls[2] = file:/home/igor/projects/javalite/activejdbc/activejdbc/target/classes/
[ERROR] urls[3] = file:/home/igor/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/slf4j-api/1.7.5/slf4j-api-1.7.5.jar
[ERROR] urls[4] = file:/home/igor/projects/javalite/activejdbc/javalite-common/target/javalite-common-1.4.10-SNAPSHOT.jar
[ERROR] urls[5] = file:/home/igor/projects/javalite/activejdbc/activejdbc/target/test-classes/
[ERROR] Number of foreign imports: 1
[ERROR] import: Entry[import  from realm ClassRealm[maven.api, parent: null]]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] -----------------------------------------------------: javassist.ClassPath
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginContainerException
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] After correcting the problems, you can resume the build with the command
[ERROR]   mvn <goals> -rf :activejdbc
```

As far as I can see, the  issue is: 
`A required class was missing while executing org.javalite:activejdbc-instrumentation:1.4.10-SNAPSHOT:instrument: javassist/ClassPath`

However this class is packaged directly into the jar file of the plugin, please see here:
https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/org/javalite/activejdbc/1.4.10-SNAPSHOT/

So, the build sometimes works, but sometimes breaks.. without any changes in code or configuration - on the same terminal window. Basically, I need to build a few times, before I get success. Please, help identify and fix the issue,

I tried Maven 3.0.4 and 3.2.3.

thanks

Comment: Does it only work after doing a mvn install?

Comment: I always do `mvn clean install`, and the problem is intermittent

Comment: If you re-run the build on only the failed project after a failure, does the failure remain?  If so, then looking at the contents from the local maven repo might provide insight.  If not, somehow it sounds like a race condition...

Comment: I was also thinking a race condition might apply. In any case, the suggestion by @CharlieS below seems to be working. I added an explicit dependency and so far I have not had build failures. Thanks all for helping. We may never know the real problem ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have a dependency on javassist in the pom..

```
<dependency> 
  <groupId>javassist</groupId>
  <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
  <version>3.18.2.GA</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: well, the entire Javassist set of classes is packaged directly into my plugin. All classes are available there, so I do not include this dependency

Comment: I don't know why maven can't find it sometimes, but that appears to be the problem. As a maven dependency it gives maven an ability to resolve the issue. I've never just dropped classes in the package, since it seems to bypass the power of maven.

Comment: The classes are dropped into the package because this package is used as a JavaAgent, so it needs to be self-sufficient. Adding a dependency to Maven seems redundant, but I will try  doing so.

Comment: Just tried adding this dependency directly to the plugin configuration and still had the same issue.

Comment: i would commit to one packaging method for all components. It appears you may be using maven for some and not others, but maven can do it all, creating self-sufficient packages. post your pom.xml for better advice :)

Comment: this is the pom for the plugin that builds successfully before activejdbc module: https://github.com/javalite/activejdbc/blob/master/activejdbc-instrumentation/pom.xml

This is the pom of the activejdbc module itself: https://github.com/javalite/activejdbc/blob/master/activejdbc/pom.xml

The activejdbc-instrumentation plugin builds successfully and uses a shale plugin to package dependencies into the jar file.

The build fails when this plugin is used to build activejdbc module.